# В Java закодировать строку как это делает браузер

Tags: кодировка, java

Можно ли штатными средствами Java преобразовать спец.символы и буквы русского алфавита в последовательность такого вида:

> %D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C

или нужно писать свою реализацию?

Comment: Я бы написал сам (просто лень искать).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Это называется *URL Encoding*. И, конечно, [в Java это есть](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URLEncoder.html).